# Clients slow to login with cached credentials off-network

Tags: windows-7, domain, login

Frustratingly enough, I can't remember *what* to search for online to fix this issue.  So I  humbly ask ServerFault to help slap the knowledge back into me.

I have a few users (not all) that tend to have very slow login times (8-10 minutes) when they are "off-network" and using cached credentials.  All users are running Win7 laptops. The domain is a 2008 R2 domain.

There aren't any GPOs currently set to affect login times (like max wait time for login scripts, etc.), and their existing GPOs are very basic and have been processed numerous times while at the office.

The laptops will login immediately if you turn off the wireless radio with their cached credentials.

I've looked at these links online hoping I could remember what to search for, but they haven't been the proper cure:

[Domained laptop - slow logon when connected to non-domain network](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a61519c7-1afc-4aeb-ba7c-a29ee5524e7b/domained-laptop-slow-logon-when-connected-to-nondomain-network?forum=itproxpsp)

[Increase domain logon timeout](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;163204&Product=win20)

[Windows 7 Slow to Load When not on Domain Network](https://superuser.com/questions/446102/windows-7-slow-to-load-when-not-on-domain-network)

Short of telling the users to disable their wireless via the slide button on their laptops before logging in, what else can I change/set for them?

Comment: Off topic and probably none of my business, but what's going on with your username?

Comment: Just a little bitterness over on SO Joe...I'll change it back at the end of the week.

Comment: Hopefully nothing too serious. You're one of the people whose questions and answers I look forward to reading.

Comment: Any chance of somehow doing wireshark? (maybe from a local logon and then switching the user to a domain logon?)

Comment: Also, have a look [here](http://www.chrisbuchanan.ca/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=17) which suggests to change the `Set maximum wait time for the network if a user has a roaming user profile or remote home directory` setting on a GPO

Comment: Also, can you see anything in the Eventlog which might be able to tell you *why* it takes time?

Comment: @MichelZ - let me look into that link and I'll grab a wireshark if possible.  I'll grab relevant eventvwr entries as well.  Should have something by tomorrow.